# How to turn off "smart" scrolling mouse wheel in OSX?

Tags: macos, scrolling, mouse-wheel

I'm currently working on OSX and it seems that Apple has built in some sort of "smart" mouse wheel scrolling where if you turn the mouse wheel slow the page moves slow and if you scroll fast the page scrolls fast. To me this is totally disorientating.

How can I turn off this behaviour and have the mouse scroll the page with a fixed pixel interval?

Answer (score 2):

System Preferences > Hardware > Mouse > One Finger > Scroll, change "with Inertia" to "without Inertia".

Comment: When I go into the Mouse preferences menu there is no such thing as "One Finger" and I don't see anything about "Inertia" anywhere. I'm on OSX 10.6.6.

Comment: So am I.  But you may need to download the most recent mouse driver/control panel, which is usually distributed with the Magic Mouse and Magic Trackpad.  (The former came with my iMac.)  http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1066